# Python netcatl's call stuck

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, netcat

I am trying to write test for my tcp port-forwarder using `netcat` but test stuck at `join`. I am trying to send and receive sample data, and then compare it.

```
def test_forwarding(self):
    route = self.config.routes[0]

    proc = subprocess.Popen(["nc -l %s" % route.sink[1]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    th = threading.Thread(target=lambda: system('nc %s %s < test_data.txt' % route.source))
    th.start()
    th.join()

    self.assertEqual(open('test_data.txt').readline(), proc.stdout.read())
```